# How do I make a global message listener that can be stopped discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How would I make a message listener that does not only work in one channel and can also be stopped when a certain command is used.

I have tried:

```
const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(()=>true);
 collector.on("collect", (collected, collector) => {
 message.author.send(collected.content)
});
bot.map.set(message.author.id, collector)
```

And the collector can be stopped by:
`bot.map.get(message.author.id).stop();`

The message listener only works for one channel and does not work for multiple channels is there a way to create a listener that works in every bot channel and can be stopped? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just add it to Message event?

Comment: You can't stop/pause a message event

Comment: You can unload an event and reload when it's needed, I mean if you want it to work in every bot channel you dont have other way, the way you do it right now it will only work in one channel where you invoke that command

Comment: So there's no way you can stop a message listener?